# How to check whether the .net is installed on the computer before starting the WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf

Currently, I have developed a WPF application using .NET 8. When distributing the application, there are two methods.

One is to use the publishing function that comes with VS to integrate the runtime.

the other is not to integrate the runtime and install the runtime on the client computer.

Since the file containing the runtime will be very large, so I chose the second option.

I hope that before starting the application, it will first determine whether the runtime is installed on the client's computer. If it is not installed, start the download. But it seems that this function cannot be implemented.

I know that ClickOnce can implement this detection, but in the end my program will package itself into a single file and can be run directly, so I don’t want to use ClickOnce.

I searched for related questions, and someone has also raised it, but the solution given seems to use c++, I don't know c++, and this solution seems to be a long time ago.

At the same time, I also tried adding a .net framework project to the solution and setting it as a startup item to determine whether the .Net 8 runtime is installed on the current computer (most windows can ensure that the .net framework starts normally. ), but in this .net framework project, the .net 8 project (my wpf main program) cannot be called.

So, is there any solution to achieve this function.

Additional information:
I finally solved this problem myself. I found a library on GitHub that perfectly solved my problem.
Address: https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper
If you need it, you can check it out.

Comment: The user will get an error message if he tries to run an application without having the proper runtime installed. The message dialog will allow the user to install the missing components if he likes to.

Comment: @BionicCode I tested it on a computer without .net, and a prompt window did pop up, but no download link was provided.

Comment: @howze: If you want to customize the "pop up" that appears when your target framework is not installed on the target machine, you need to provide some kind of custom installer. Why don't you use either ClickOnce, MSIX or simply distribute your app as a self-contained paclage that includes the .NET 8 runtime?

Comment: @mm8 Firstly, I would like the application to be a single file, so that users can run it by double clicking without the need for installation. So I can only choose to publish self-contained programs, but the encryption software I am using currently does not support encrypting such self-contained programs, which is what troubles me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional information: I finally solved this problem myself. I found a library on GitHub that perfectly solved my problem. Address: https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper If you need it, you can check it out.

Comment: I realize they are wanting to deploy a WPF project and obviously that's going to be targeting only Windows runtime, but at that point you could just as easily use a PowerShell script to download and run the .NET setup `.exe`, install via [winget](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli), or whatever else. Publishing self-contained is definitely the best option for .NET Core projects.

Comment: Also, that is by far the most annoying "Russia bad" [section](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DotnetRuntimeBootstrapper/blob/f307d99470b3e22cc6d6955355910c77b3b3b08b/Readme.md#terms-of-use) I've ever seen in a README.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the .NET Core installs. The SDKs are installed to a different place than the runtimes.

**.NET SDK:**
`C:\program files\dotnet\sdk\{version}\`

**.NET Runtime:**
`C:\program files\dotnet\shared\{runtime-type}\{version}\`

For example, .NET 8.0 desktop runtime is installed to `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\8.0.0`.

Having said that, you should just build (or publish) a self-contained executable. You can make it single file or not, that's up to you, but publishing a self-contained project will include the necessary runtime dependencies.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
  <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
  <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
  <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Edit: A note on the publish size, publishing self-contained is actually smaller compared to downloading and then installing the full .NET runtime. By the time you finished downloading the app and then the bootstrapper someone linked above finishes downloading the installer the app could already be running and without prompting the user.

Self-contained publishes can also be trimmed by adding `<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>` to the project file. There's other options that offer more granular control as well ([see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming/trimming-options?pivots=dotnet-8-0)).